# Windows, filtering mouse device input before displaying ? Have some questions about getting started

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, winapi

I am looking into writing something similar to that of [Steady Mouse](http://www.steadymouse.com/). My grandpa has tremors pretty badly and it prevents him from doing too much on the computer. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work on Windows 10 and it seems the developer has discontinued working on the project. Seeing as I am looking for project to add to my portfolio, I figured I would see if I could maybe hack something together, only problem being I've never done anything this low level before so I am unsure of where to begin.

It seems the Kalman Filter is my best bet as an filtering algorithm, but I am unsure of how to provide the input. I've never used the Windows API, is this something it provides? Or, do I instead hook directly into the mouse device itself, and how is this possible? Am I even on the right track here?

I am assuming this would best be a background running process booted on startup, that filters the device input before the OS draws the cursor on the screen. Obviously, this would need to access all events and mouse movements regardless of which program is being used.

Comment: Besides your good intentions regarding your grandpa, this question is a bit overly broad don't you think so?

Comment: One starting point is a "Lower-Level Filter Driver" quote:  "For example, a lower-level class filter driver for mouse devices could provide acceleration, performing a nonlinear conversion of mouse movement data."  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545890(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Dustin in your link, the author of Steady Mouse gives an email address. Although he says he hasn't had much time, you could still make a request for a Windows 10 version. You can also volunteer to be a Beta test site!

Comment: Besides the good intention, this question boils down to "I want to do something, and don't know how. What do I need to do?". It isn't even specific about a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate Windows Message Hook functions, it is possible to intercept/change Windows messages such as WM_MOUSEMOVE.